# why am I getting this error while parsing the swift JSON?

Tags: swift

Why I am getting the error while parsing the data
Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
struct jsondata: Decodable {
      let id: Int
      let name: String
      let link: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

        let jsonUrlString = "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/jsondecodable/courses_missing_fields"

        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return}

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {return}

            do{
                let course = try JSONDecoder().decode([jsondata].self, from: data)
                print(jsondata.link)
            }
            catch let jsonerr{
                print("error serilizing",jsonerr)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me error

Comment: bro im getting this error (Instance member 'link' cannot be used on type 'jsondata')

Comment: this **print(jsondata.link)** is meaningless ,  you need **print(course)**

Comment: Ca you show your response, I think you are getting the different type of "link"

Comment: so how should i print it (name,id,link)over there?

Comment: @WorldEdit tried printing course ??

Comment: It will help improve legibility and get responses if you follow standards such as capitalizing types (jsondata in this case should be JSONData)

Answer (score 0):

Make option the parameter according to requirement:

```
let id: Int?
let name: String?
let link: String?
```

And if you are getting array of object in response then

```
let course = try JSONDecoder().decode([jsondata].self, from: data)
print(course.first.link)
```

And if you are getting without Array:

```
let course = try JSONDecoder().decode(jsondata.self, from: data)
print(course.link)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the list of items returned from the server in the JSON array, the last item has the only name. There is no id, link, imageUrl or number_of_lessons fields available. In order to match this scenario, you need to make id and link as optional by adding `?`. If you don't know much about optionals, I suggest you [read this article at medium](https://medium.com/swift2go/swift-optionals-for-beginners-8833afad4697).

when you parse the JSON and retrieve a courses array, there is no need to access the JSON data that you used for parsing. Since you have a much readable courses objects inside an array, simply access it with the index. Here for an example, I've accessed the 0th index by typing `print(course[0].link)`.

By the way, please don't access elements directly using the index in a production-ready code because you never know how many elements were returned from the server.

your code should look something like below.

```
import UIKit
struct jsondata: Decodable {
    let id: Int?
    let name: String
    let link: String?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let jsonUrlString = "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/jsondecodable/courses_missing_fields"

        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return}

        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {return}

            do{
                let course = try JSONDecoder().decode([jsondata].self, from: data)
                print(course[0].link)
//                print(jsondata.link)
            }
            catch let jsonerr{
                print("error serilizing",jsonerr)
            }
        }

        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```